# Mendeley stuck on full screen

Tags: macos-highsierra, mendeley

I am using Mendeley Desktop v 1.19.1 on my macOS High Sierra v 10.13.4. 
Mendeley is stuck on full screen. It opens in that way and I cannot exit full screen or move it around. The “File” menu at the top does not disappear and is stuck on top of the close and minimize button, as in the picture below. I tried uninstalling this and reinstalling and still no change.

[image]

This problem is only with Mendeley.

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you tried to go to Mendeley menu -> View -> Exit Full Screen? It uses to work for me. Another workaround is using "Misson Control" (F3) where I can move mendeley over desktops.

Answer (score 3):

I had this too and fixed it by quitting the app, deleting the Mendeley preferences files in the preferences folder, then re-opening Mendeley.

Comment: The question says “I tried uninstalling this and reinstalling and still no change.”  It seems odd that your answer would be more effective than a reinstall.

Comment: @Scott Standard methods of uninstalling software on macOS wouldn't delete the preferences file.

Comment: hey @Lachlan does this delete all the folder and categories  that I made inside Mendeley to sort my files?

Comment: @Lachlan  Could you please elaborate where the preferences folder is located?

Comment: @EvgenyTanhilevich it's located at ~/Library/Preferences

Comment: Also, this didn't work for me - even after quitting the app, deleting the preferences files, and reinstalling the app.

Comment: Had the same problem - the solution didn't work at first, but then I realized that there are multiple files in ~/Library/Preferences that start with com.mendeley so I ereased all of them and the problem seems to have vanished.

Comment: Just select in the menu "exit full screen", quit the application and relaunch. That fixes the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you open the preferences menu of the application, the windows is back to normal.

Comment: This did not work for me.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem. I reset Mendeley and everything works fine.

Use `Help`→`Reset Mendeley Desktop`.